# Standardising plot text to word document font size 10 (R)

Tags: text, fonts

I need to produce some plots for a publication, which requires all text on the figures to be in a specific size and font. How can I achieve this in both base and ggplot2? I found some threads that suggest using `pointsize=` in the output function like this:

```
tiff(paste0(wd,"figure_1.tiff"), units="mm", width=90, height=90, res=500, pointsize = 10)
plot1 <- df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x= x, y= y, fill= x)) +
  geom_violin() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.9, option="A") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=10, family = "Arial")
  )
dev.off()
```

But this either doesn't seem to work, or doesn't affect the text that is generated in the text() function. I have similar problems trying to apply it in base R.

```
tiff(paste0(wd,"figure_1.tiff"), units="mm", width=180, height=90, res=500, pointsize = 10)
boxplot(y ~ x, data = df, col = "white", outline = FALSE, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
text(x=0.5, y=2000, "a)", xpd=NA)
stripchart(y ~ x,
           data = df,
           method = "jitter",
           pch = 1,
           cex = 0.5,
           col = c(1,4,7),
           vertical = TRUE,
           add = TRUE)
abline(h = 500, lty = 3, lwd = 3, col = 'red')
dev.off()
```

How can I ensure it works in both the plot labels and the text printed on the plot (like "a)", "b)") etc.?